# Bounds on dependent truncated random variable with given mean and variance

Tags: truncated-distributions

I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ with given (mean, standard deviation) as $(\mu_{X}, \sigma_{X})$ and $(\mu_{Y}, \sigma_{Y})$, respectively. These random variables have their truncated counterparts: $tr(X) = max(0,X)$ and $tr(Y) = max(0,Y)$. We know the mean and standard deviation of the truncated counterparts too: $(\mu_{tr(X)}, \sigma_{tr(X)})$ and $(\mu_{tr(Y)}, \sigma_{tr(Y)})$.

Can we say anything about the covariance of the truncated random variables (i.e., $E[tr(X), tr(Y)$])?

Some conditions:

1. The distributions of the original or the truncated random variables are not available.
2. The variables are most certainly dependent because of the setup of the underlying experiment, so bounds from the Chebychev inequality will not be ideal to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
-\sigma_X \sigma_Y
\le
-\sigma_{tr(X)} \sigma_{tr(Y)}
\le
Cov(tr(X),tr(Y))
\le
\sigma_{tr(X)} \sigma_{tr(Y)}
\le
\sigma_X \sigma_Y
$$
Those inequalities are basic, but are probably all that can be said.

Consider $X$ with a discrete uniform distribution between 1 and 100, and $Y=X-99$. Then $X$ and $Y$ have correlation of +1 but the truncated versions have correlation close to 0.

Similarly consider $X$ with a discrete uniform distribution between -99 and 1, and
$$
Y =
\begin{cases}
\phantom{-X1}1 \phantom{99.}\text{ if }X=1\\
-X-99 \text{ if }X\le 0
\end{cases}
$$
Then $X$ and $Y$ have correlation to close to -1 but the truncated versions have correlation of +1.